# what is All heap Allocations and All Anonymous Allocations in Xcode Instruments allocations?

Tags: ios, instruments, allocation

I hava an application . when I repeat some action , anonymous allocations memory continuously increase a lot while heap allocations increase  a little.  can some one help me ? Thanks

Comment: some code? a little  description about your app?

Comment: my app crashes with at a given point, and even running zombies instrument it doesn't give a reason, just checks the box 'All heap allocations' ad highlights in blue. Is this a simiar problem to @AndyHong 's?

Answer (score 1):

Focus on the Live Bytes column for All Heap Allocations to see how much memory your application is using. You cannot control your application's Anonymous VM size.

> Focus on the heap allocations because your app has more control over
> heap allocations. **Most of the memory allocations your app makes are
> heap allocations.**
>
> The VM in anonymous VM stands for virtual memory.
> When your app launches, the operating system reserves a block of
> virtual memory for your application. This block is usually much larger
> than the amount of memory your app needs. When your app allocates
> memory, the operating system allocates the memory from the block it
> reserved.
>
> Remember the second sentence in the previous paragraph. The operating
> system determines the size of the virtual memory block, not your app.
> That’s why you should focus on the heap allocations instead of
> anonymous VM. **Your app has no control over the size of the anonymous
> VM.**

Source: http://meandmark.com/blog/2014/01/instruments-heap-allocations-and-anonymous-vm/